# XlsxWriter error for percent format

Tags: python, pandas, xlsxwriter

I'm using Pandas and exporting data to excel using XlsxWriter. 
One of the data columns has floats and needs to be formatted as percent, so this is  how I do it:

```
percent_fmt = workbook.add_format({'num_format': '0.00%'})
worksheet.set_column('E:E', percent_fmt)
```

After that the following error appears:

> File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\xlsxwriter\worksheet.py", line 4688,
>   in _write_col_info
>       / float(max_digit_width) * 256.0) / 256.0
>
> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'Format' and 'int'

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You need to specify a width before the format or None if you don't want to adjust the width.

```
worksheet.set_column('E:E', None, percent_fmt)
```

Comment: I want to use this, but I don't have the `workbook` object that is necessary to create the `percent_fmt` setting here. Is it possible to create `percent_fmt` some other way? I looked on your docs and importing xlsxwriter and pulling the workbook object from it may not work for my application.

Comment: You will need a reference to the parent workbook in order to create a new format. And it isn't possible to get a workbook reference from a worksheet. You will either need to pass in the format you want to use or the workbook object so you can generate a format. The first is the better option.

Comment: Thanks. I've got the entire thing written around df.to_excel() so it's hard to get the workbook object.. unless you have an easy way to do that in such cases?

Comment: See the following for how to get the XlsxWriter workbook object: https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_pandas.html

Comment: AH! I can't believe how many times I looked for that and never found this page. Thank you for a great writer!  I use it extensively :)